# Python 3 ERROR: Package 'openpyxl' requires a different Python: 3.5.3 not in '>=3.6, '

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip, openpyxl

Trying to install python package import_export

I've tried to install a python module:

```
virtualenv .
source bin/activate
pip3 install -U django-import-export
```

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting django-import-export
  Using cached django_import_export-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: Django>=2.0 in /home/pi/inventree-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from django-import-export) (2.2.9)
Collecting diff-match-patch
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/diff-match-patch/diff_match_patch-20181111-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Collecting tablib<1.0.0
  Using cached tablib-0.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz in /home/pi/inventree-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Django>=2.0->django-import-export) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: sqlparse in /home/pi/inventree-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Django>=2.0->django-import-export) (0.3.0)
Collecting xlrd
  Using cached xlrd-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Collecting markuppy
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/markuppy/MarkupPy-1.14-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 kB)
Collecting xlwt
  Using cached xlwt-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (99 kB)
Collecting openpyxl>=2.4.0
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/openpyxl/openpyxl-3.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (241 kB)
ERROR: Package 'openpyxl' requires a different Python: 3.5.3 not in '>=3.6, '
```

I also installed

`sudo apt-get install python3-openpyxl`

Which works.

However

```
ImportError: No module named 'import_export'
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: The exception tells you all you need to know: you'll need Python 3.6 or higher. Or, you can install openpyxl < 3 first.

Comment: Oh thats bad. I though II had python 3.6 and the error was that I needed Python 3.5.3